Conditional type only works with "as const" on string literal. How could I make it not require "as const"?
I'm playing around with conditional types in TypeScript and I'm faced with an issue.
Basically, TypeScript seems incapable of correctly discerning the type I want, despite the fact that the argument should be a constant.
Here's my code:
const resistanceColor = [
  { color: "black", value: 100 },
  { color: "brown", value: 200 },
  // ...etc
] as const;

type Color = typeof resistanceColor[number]['color'];
// type: "black" | "brown" | ...etc
type ColorValue = typeof resistanceColor[number]['value'];
// type: 100 | 200
type Res<S> = S extends Color ? ColorValue : 'Error';

export function colorCode<S>(color: S): Res<S> {
  const index = resistanceColor.find((item) => item.color === color)?.value
  if (index === undefined) {
    return 'Error' as Res<S>;
  }
  return index as Res<S>;
};

// Issue 

const ok1 = colorCode(resistanceColor[0].color);
// Has correct type of `ColorValue`
const ok2 = colorCode('banana');
// Has the correct type of 'Error'
const err = colorCode('black');
// Has type 'Error'; despite it being a good color
const annoying = colorCode('black' as const);
// Has correct type of `ColorValue`, but requires as const

My issue stems from the fact that I don't particularly feel like adding the as const to the string 'black'. Even more confusing is this interaction:
const color_err = 'black';
const color_confusing = 'black' as const;
colorCode(color_err); // type 'Error'
colorCode(color_confusing); // type 'ColorValue'

Note that because both color_* variables are constant then the type is the literal string black - and yet I still require the as const variable.
I've tried restring the original S generic to extend from string. But I don't want this, I want the colorCode function to accept as argument any value and type. Furthermore it lead to a very bizarre situation:
export function colorCode<S extends string>(color: S): Res<S> { /* ...etc */ }
// This works now!
const neat1 = colorCode('red');
// But this doesn't
colorCode([] as unknown); // error - unknown can't extend string
let oh_no: unknown = []
colorCode(oh_no); // evaluates to ColorValue! Which is even worse

I'm currently using tsserver version 4.3.3 as well as tsc version 5.4.3.

Is your question “why” like in the title? If so it’s because for unconstrained type parameters people usually don’t want literal types, so that’s the default behavior. Or is the question “how do I fix it” as the body implies? If so I’d say “use a const type parameter as introduced in TS5.0. Could you [edit] to make it clear which question you are asking?

@jcalz Edited the question because I do want to know why and how to fix it.

So it’s two questions? It makes sense that you want both but one should be primary. If you get two answers, one which details exactly why it’s happening, and another which details exactly how to fix it, which one is correct? If one question duplicates an existing SO question and the other doesn’t, what happens when someone closes this as a duplicate? Please [edit] so it’s clear which single specific question you’re asking. Any reasonable answer will touch on both, I’m sure.

Edited the question title again. Feel free to suggest any alternative titles you might consider more appropriate

See this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer (or find a suitable duplicate). If not, what am I missing?

Yes - it's ideal.

Please see the linked questions/answers above for more information.
